# Passing data to child component but getting undefined after onChanges

Tags: angular, rxjs

Can anybode answer, why after passing data to childs component, this.rows becomes and passed data become undefined
parent component:

```
this.report$ = this.finInfoClient.getFinancialOperationsReport(params);
<div class="card-body p-0 d-flex flex-column" *ngIf="report$ | async as rep">
<div class="row flex-row flex-fill">
<app-financial-operations-grid [data]="rep.operations"
(gridItemSelected)="itemSelected($event)">
</app-financial-operations-grid>
</div>
</div>
```

child component:

```
@Input() data: FinancialOperation[];
rows: FinancialOperation[] | null;
get root(): FinancialOperation[] {return this.rows.filter(d => d.parentId === undefined || d.parentId === null);}
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   if (changes['data']) {
       this.rows = this.data;
   }
}
```

and after `onChanges` completed all local variables become undefined

Comment: Why do you need another variable to store the input data? It's already present in the 'data' variable in your case. I can see only data and rows as your local variables, and both refers to same value, put a breakpoint inside if(changes['data']) condition, I think it's getting hit more than once, and last hit may have undefined data in it, which is resetting both local variables as undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   const dataChange = changes.data;

   if (dataChange != undefined ) {
     this.rows = dataChange.currentValue
   }
}
```

Comment: in both cases inside method all is good, but when it completes all variables suddenly become undefined

Comment: Share it in stackbiltz

Answer (score 0):

Your `report` is a stream. You might need to pass your `report.operations` to child component with `async` pipe too.

Like this:

```
<app-financial-operations-grid [data]="(report$ | async).operations"
...
```

Comment: that's why where is report$ | async as rep
but also tried - doesn't solve the problem